Router fritzbox not answering ping from machine on other subnet
My environment has 2 networks with a gateway that communicates ip addresses (dhcp, dnsmasq) and routes for both networks. Most machines should use the 2nd network that will use a openvpn connection via router in the future (not active yet). The 1st network uses a fritzbox as router and gateway. Working. The 2nd network is installed but uses the fritzbox as router, too, for preparation and because the other is not ready. Also working.
For some serious tests I ping from some machines to router on different subnets.
Some results:

Network 1



Machine-a -> Router = success




Machine-a -> Gateway = success


Network 2



Machine-a -> Router = no success




Machine-a -> Gateway = success




Machine-b -> Router = no success




Machine-b -> Gateway = success




Machine-a -> Network-1-machine-* = success



So ...

Network-1-machine-* -> Router = success
Network-2-machine-* -> Router = no success

So routing works.
This Network-setup shows parts of the network. Pls ignore 2nd router (right side).
I want to enable internet access via fritzbox for network 1 & 2 for the time while the future setup is not activated. Maybe the workaround is to use gateway as dns server.
Did I miss an option in fritzbox that allows and answers pings from other subnets?

Can you draw a diagram of how everything is connected? I can't make sense of "as router and gateway"... generally router and gateway are the same thing. Do you mean different things by those?

@grawity_u1686 Text edited, inserted link to pic.

The router fritzbox connects network-a with internet via isp, gateway should connect network-a with network-b.

I just don't know excatly what I need there. Routes in every machine, routes only in gateway (active) or just info for gateway in every machine? 2 of the options work except router-ping-answer :(

Found my solution.
Turns out that every machine, that wants to use the route (to other network), needs to set the route (maybe it's called active routing. Pls correct me if I'm wrong). I did that via dhcp-option ... But only for "normal" machines, not for the router (fritzbox) itself, that has static ip properties but without routing.

If a package from other network comes in and the machine=router handles the ip address, without routing to that (src) network it simply doesn't know where to deliver it (back). With routing (static) it does know it and is able to deliver "back" -> answering works.

Now also internet connection works in network-2 with router in network-1 because of routing :) (Other plans for future)
